# data binding in pivot element from 2 different sources using x:Bind

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need to bind my pivot header template to Course_Tab data and the gridview inside item template to Course_Products data using **x:Bind**. I have successfully completed the binding of the pivot header template but getting the item source for the gridview has been a bit difficult for me because of some datatemplate error.
Here is the code snippet:

```
public ObservableCollection<CourseList> Course_Tab { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Productdetails> Course_Products { get; set; }


 [DataContract]
public class CourseList
{
    [DataMember]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CourseCategoryCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string BoardCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CourseDisplayName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CourseShortName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Productdetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AcademicYearCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Product_Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Product_Subtype { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SDcardsize { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Graphics { get; set; }
}


<Pivot x:Name="Pivot1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Course_Tab}" SelectionChanged="Pivot1_SelectionChanged">
                <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:CourseList">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CourseDisplayName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

                <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Course_Products}">
                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Productdetails">
                                    <Image Source="{x:Bind Graphics}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        </GridView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.ItemTemplate>

            </Pivot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want to do is to bind nested GridView inside Pivot. In your code, you bind a `ItemsSource` to the Pivot control and then you want to bind a collection to a GridView which is inside the Pivot item. So for the GridView's collection it is a nested collection.

To bind this, we need to change the data model of `CourseList` to add the Course_Products as one of the properties of `CourseList` like follows:

```
public class CourseList
{
   [DataMember]
   public int CourseID { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string CourseCategoryCode { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string BoardCode { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string CourseCode { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string CourseName { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string CourseDisplayName { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string CourseShortName { get; set; }

   public ObservableCollection<Productdetails> Course_Products { get; set; }
```

}

And the XAML code:

```
<Pivot x:Name="Pivot1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Course_Tab}" SelectionChanged="Pivot1_SelectionChanged">
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CourseList">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CourseDisplayName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CourseList">
            <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Course_Products}">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Productdetails">
                        <Image Source="{x:Bind Graphics}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

And sample for data source:

```
 Course_Tab = new ObservableCollection<CourseList>
 {
     new CourseList {CourseDisplayName="displayname1" ,Course_Products= new ObservableCollection<Productdetails>
     {
         new Productdetails {Graphics="Assets/caffe1.jpg" },
         new Productdetails {Graphics="Assets/caffe2.jpg" }
     }},
     new CourseList {CourseDisplayName="displayname2" ,Course_Products= new ObservableCollection<Productdetails>
     {
          new Productdetails {Graphics="Assets/caffe1.jpg" }
     }}
 };
```

Comment: Is it not possible to bind it without modifying the data model of CourseList. What I am looking to do is bind two very different data sources without any kind of nesting for the header and item template.

Comment: In that case, you can put the `CourseList` and `Productdetails` into one parent source(let both  of them be the child collections of the parent source ). Anyway, the `ItemsSource` for the `Pivot` can only be one.